# exported const variable is undefined in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6-modules, vue-cli

I’m using @vue/cli for a project and I can’t for the life of me figure out why my exported variables aren't working. This is my code setup:

**[App.vue]**

```
import {somevar} from './main.js'
console.log(somevar)
```

**[main.js]**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
const somevar = "example"
export {somevar}

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

When I run **npm run serve**, *somevar* is just coming back as undefined in the browser console…?

I’ve tried to do this with a vanilla setup (not in vue) and it works, so I assume it’s something going on specifically with vue?

Comment: Is App.vue importing main.js and main.js importing App.vue? Are the imports circular? Maybe it has to do with https://www.jscodetips.com/examples/circular-imports-with-webpack-returning-empty-object

Comment: It has nothing to do with Vue. It works for me in both vue-cli, vite and [SFC playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cbmltcG9ydCB7IHNvbWV2YXIgfSBmcm9tICcuL3Rlc3QuanMnXG5jb25zb2xlLmxvZyhzb21ldmFyKVxuPC9zY3JpcHQ+XG5cbjx0ZW1wbGF0ZT5cbnt7c29tZXZhcn19XG48L3RlbXBsYXRlPiIsImltcG9ydC1tYXAuanNvbiI6IntcbiAgXCJpbXBvcnRzXCI6IHtcbiAgICBcInZ1ZVwiOiBcImh0dHBzOi8vc2ZjLnZ1ZWpzLm9yZy92dWUucnVudGltZS5lc20tYnJvd3Nlci5qc1wiXG4gIH1cbn0iLCJ0ZXN0LmpzIjoiY29uc3Qgc29tZXZhciA9IFwiZXhhbXBsZVwiXG5leHBvcnQgeyBzb21ldmFyIH0ifQ==).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to import main.js in App.vue which itself is imported in main.js (cyclic dependency).

I tried to repoduce your setup which resulted in a `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'App' before initialization` in the browser console (I have a project based on vite 2 and vue 3).

I'd suggest to extract the constant in an additional javascript file like example.js and import it in App.vue (and main.js if necessary).

The following setup works for me.

**[App.vue]**

```
<script setup>
import { somevar } from './example.js'
console.log(somevar)
</script>
```

**[main.js]**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

**[example.js]**

```
const somevar = "example"
export {somevar}
```

Comment: That's great, I didn't realise that main.js was a kind of reserved file for vue. It works now with your suggested tweak, still learning! Many thanks!